# Excel date format - quarter & year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to change the cell format to display quarter and year *q yyyy* instead of *dd-mm-yyyy*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - quarters are not a customisable format

The closest I think you could get would be to use a formula which has two potential limitations

1. in place of the current value
2. which would then no longer be a date

`=INDEX({"Mar","Jun","Sep","Dec"},ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0))&TEXT(A1," yyyy")`

will return the quarter (based on a calendar year) and year of a date in A1, i.e. for today's date
Dec 2011

Comment: Plus this would be in another column than the cell in which user is inputting the data :)

Comment: which is covered by point (1), in the "two potential limitations"

Answer (score 5):

```
=ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0)&TEXT(A1," yyyy")
```

This is enough if you just need the number of the quarter

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have the said format.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF([@Date]="","N/A",TEXT([@Date],"YYYY-Q")&ROUNDUP(MONTH([@Date])/3,0))

=IF(A1="","N/A",TEXT(A1,"YYYY-Q")&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0)
```

e.g., `6/15/2015` will become `2015-Q3`

Just in case the date field is blank this formula will fill with `N/A` instead of getting `1900-Q1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
="Q"&INT((MONTH(AZ2)+2)/3)&"-"&YEAR(AZ2)
```

This will take `12/31/2016` in cell `AZ2` and change it to `Q4-2016`

Answer (score 0):

For 1/7/2020 in cell A1,

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyy")&"Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2)/3,0)
```

Produces:  "2020Q1"